# Wine runs fine from .wine folder, but not from flash drive

Tags: wine

I've done some reading on this and found out that there are some complications with Wine running on flash drives. While I don't completely understand why these complications exist (meaning that I'm a dummy and don't understand why the instructions were telling me to do certain things, therefore I may have botched it) I did follow instructions to solve the issue to no avail.

What I'm trying to do is run games on my Chromebook. I installed crouton, gnome terminal, and then Wine. The chromebook is limited by a very small internal drive, meaning that I can't store all of the games I want to play on the device itself, I have to load them onto a flash drive and play them from there. I was able to get some games working when I copied them into the `.Wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/(game directory).exe` and ran the command:

```
 wine ./(game directory).exe
```

but I want to get them to work by running:

```
wine /media/removable/USB20FD/(game directory).exe
```

but it won't work, instead giving me this:

```
(precise)matthew@localhost:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files$ wine /media/removable/USB20FD/halo/halo.exe/
err:module:import_dll Library vorbisfile.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\media\\removable\\USB20FD\\halo\\halo.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library binkw32.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\media\\removable\\USB20FD\\halo\\halo.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\media\\removable\\USB20FD\\halo\\halo.exe" failed, status c0000135
(precise)matthew@localhost:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files$
```

So far this same (or really similar) error message has been generated regardless of the game I try. So I know the problem isn't just with this particular game.

Any help would be really appreciated, or if you have suggestions on how I could do this better I am open to ideas. Thanks everybody.

Note:
    I failed and am retaking my college linux class for good reason. I am not a genius on this system and I fail to grasp certain concepts. Therefore I'd really appreciate simple steps, maybe some definitions of things as you go along, and I'm sorry if I have to ask dumb questions. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I installed, or at least tried to install Wine on my chromebook and it just wouldn't work.  It appears the chrome flavor of linux is bastardized to not comply with wine, and I suspect this limitation was intentional on the part of Google, but I admit that is speculation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I'm fairly certain the Chromebook isn't the problem exactly, since Wine works on Windows .exe files on my Chromebooks internal drive. I think it's just difficult to get Wine to work with a flash drive.